# cannot open directory - Stale file handle

Tags: docker

I am trying to mount a folder when running a docker image

```
docker run -it -v ${PWD}:/logs myimage:latest bash
```

but when I list the mounted directory inside the container the following error occurs:

```
bash-4.4$ ls /logs
ls: cannot open directory '/logs': Stale file handle
```

What is missing here?

Answer (score 0):

probably a permission is needed to read/write that folder, try to define a user as the the host user which probably has the permission. `--user $(id -u):$(id -g)`

```
   docker run -it -v ${PWD}:/logs --user $(id -u):$(id -g) myimage:latest bash
```